# Angular file download breaks UTF-8 BOM

Tags: angular, csv, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have made script with PHP which is used for generating CSV file with UTF-8 BOM encoding and it works fine whenever I download file through url, like:
www.example.com/generateCSV

PHP code:

```
   $file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'mycsv');
   $df = fopen($file, 'w');
   fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
   fputcsv($df, ['sd123123123čęėąėąčę', 'ąčęąčęąęąčę'], ';');
   fclose($df);

   header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=csv.csv');
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
   readfile($file);
```

However, when I download file with angular, I get problem with encoding. Characters are not more recognised as UTF-8 valid and they break.
For csv file download I use this angular code:

```
t.prototype.downloadCsv = function () {
      var t = this, e = {
        date_from: this.helpers.formatDate(this.filter.date_from),
        date_to: this.helpers.formatDate(this.filter.date_to),
        download: "fees"
      };
      this.http.get("team-accounts/" + this.route.snapshot.params.id, e).subscribe(function (n) {
        var i = {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"},
          r = t.account.team.name + "_summary_" + e.date_from + "_" + e.date_to + ".csv";
        t.helpers.downloadFile(n._body, i, r)
      })
    }
```

Does any one sees what could be the problem ?
Why loading page through direct link works fine, but then I load it through angular it stops displaying characters correctly ?

downloadFile function:

```
t.prototype.downloadFile = function (t, e, n, i) {
      var r = new Blob([t], e);
      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) navigator.msSaveBlob(r, n); else {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        if (void 0 !== a.download) {
          var o = i || document.body, s = URL.createObjectURL(r);
          a.setAttribute("href", s), a.setAttribute("download", n), a.style.visibility = "hidden", o.appendChild(a), a.click(), o.removeChild(a)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: BOM indicates if the the byte order is little or big endian. That's relevant for 16, 32 and bigger quantities. It's not relevant for UTF-8, which uses only 8 bit quantities. BOM for UTF-8 is therefore non-sense, outside the standard and deprecated.

Comment: It's easy to imagine how a direct download works: you click a link and the browser does the rest. For Angular however, there are many ways to do it. So add more information to your question: What does `t.helpers.downloadFile` do (show the code)? Is the result displayed in the Angular app or first saved as a file on PC? What processing does Angular do to the file?

Comment: @Codo I have added downloadFile function code in the answer

Comment: @Codo: no, it is not outside standard and it is not deprecated. Unicode has few uses cases of UTF-8 BOM, and it says explicitly that UTF-8 BOM should not be removed, if it was on the original document. I can agree that it is bad taste, but it seems it is the best way Microsoft could catch up UTF-8 as first class encoding (as in Unix/Linux/macos), just to distinguish text from Latin1 and its extensions. It is just taking too much time for the really needed transition.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. But do you any suggestions how to solve this problem ? I've been stuck with this almost 2 weeks already. I guess `var r = new Blob([t], e);` is creating new csv file, which is not UTF-8 BOM encoded?

Comment: What about if you download it as text? CSV do not like BOM (you see it also in R): the first line should have headers, so BOM could be used as first character of first column name. Often it is better to treat them as text, and just split fields at coma [if you do not have strings with coma, and so more complex csv] [but you are not using csv helper]. What error do you get [check also dev mode]? Is it consistent on all browsers?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it works fine for most browsers or csv readers, except windows excel. Users need to get CSV file, so txt wouldn't be an option there.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: you really do no need to use "Content-Type: text/csv;". This field is just for browsers, and they should not care about internal format. Excel and most programs will just use extension or explicit file format. -- On the other hand, I misunderstood you where the problem is. But so you need to check byte per byte what it is the difference on the files produced by Angular and by download the file directly. This will help understanding the problem. BTW are you sure your PHP is producing `sd123123123čęėąėąčę` as Unicode?

Comment: Same issue here, handling a csv with BOM character and the Angular HttpClient just remove the BOM character.